# Linux process activities

Tags: sql, linux, process, trace

Is there possibility to show what's going on under specified process in Linux?

For example, i run **SQL query** -> **select evil_function();**
and notice that process under Linux uses all cpu.

So is there something with what I can see **whats going on under this process**?

What I want is to see what queries is running under this process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strace` will tell you what *system calls* the process is making.

To see what called routines are taking the most CPU, you need to run a profiling tool, and make sure the executable of the process you in compiled correctly (sometimes it needs to be instrumented during compilation for profiling, sometimes it just needs to be compiled with debug symbols, or not stripped of them after compilation).

You might want to look at `oprofile`, `valgrind`, `gprof` and for starters on free tools - there are also commercial products available.

Here are a few links:

http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/profiling/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a whole bunch of things.

If you are talking about MySQL do:

```
show processlist;
```

For info specifically about linux processes, you can `strace` the process to get a list of system function that it calls. Unless you are experienced with linux this will be useless to you.

If the process is paused then you can find out what function it is stopped on, but that's probably not what you want, since you say the process is running.

There are also various tools that can give you info on what parts of the disk the process is reading, and how much memory it's allocating.

And finally you can use `gdb` to break into the process and single step your way through it to see exactly what it's doing. This will also likely be useless to you since an SQL server does a LOT of things - far to many to understand by this method.